# How to load core data into a struct

Tags: swift, core-data, struct, fetch, swift5

I want to load core data into struct CusomData. Attribute atBATS should be loaded into var title. Attribute image should be loaded into var backgroundIMage. I have my struct and where it is called in the view controller.

```
      struct CustomData {
var title: String
var backgroundImage: UIImage
       }


  class ViewController: UIViewController {

fileprivate let data = [
    CustomData(title: "The Islands!", backgroundImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "islandZero")),
    CustomData(title: "Subscribe to maxcodes boiiii!", backgroundImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "islandThree")),
    CustomData(title: "StoreKit Course!", backgroundImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "islandZero")),

]
    }
```

Comment: Add an init method in your struct which takes a `NSManagedObject` (subclass) parameter and map the attributes.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are really asking, what is the problem with doing what you want?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have 2 attributes string atBats and Binary Data image I want them to fill in var title and var background image. So when instead of manually writing the title like above I just want to fetch it from core data.

Comment: So the question is how to fetch data from Core Data?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes and fetch it into a struct if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to make CustomData a NSManagedObject with a `title` and `backgroundImage` property. Core Data only works with objects that inherit from `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: No, NSManagedObject is it's own type that inherits from NSObject. I would recommend watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMze4tT2w_U) on Core Data as it works much differently than other objects.

Comment: So I should do this without using a struct. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, if you want to implement CoreData you should not be using a struct for your object.